# I am having difficulty getting this formula to work in google docs

Tags: excel, google-docs

I "think" I am trying to created a nested IF function in google docs. 
I am using the formula:

```
=IF(('Roast Calc'!E6>24,(('Roast Calc'!E6-25)/5),('Roast Calc'!E6/5)),IF('Roast Calc'!J6>24,(('Roast Calc'!J6-25)/5),('Roast Calc'!J6/5)),IF('Roast Calc'!X6>24,(('Roast Calc'!X6-25)/5),('Roast Calc'!X6/5)))
```

I am receiving a formula Parse error.

Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: You have three different calculations.  IF is set up `IF(Criteria,What to do when true, what to do when false)` you are trying to add a forth.  Please explain in words what you want to do.

Comment: I would like all three calculations to be added together. Do I also need to add a sum function to the beginning of the formula?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was defiantly going about that the wrong way, thank you for your help.

Comment: If my answer below worked for you please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you once again, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the three IFs together:

```
=('Roast Calc'!E6 -IF('Roast Calc'!E6>24,25,0))/5+('Roast Calc'!J6 -IF('Roast Calc'!J6>24,25,0))/5+('Roast Calc'!X6 -IF('Roast Calc'!X6>24,25,0))/5
```